# "The" with abstract nouns

Tags: definite-article, abstract-nouns

Is there any difference between A and B?

A: How the GRH movement led to acceptance of Ivermectin as a COVID-19 therapy in Peru?

B: How the GRH movement led to **THE** acceptance of Ivermectin as a COVID-19 therapy in Peru?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite article is used for *specific* things, so it depends whether you are speaking about a general acceptance of something, or a specific, formal act of acceptance.

For example:

> He gained acceptance in the town.

This doesn't need an article because it doesn't point to anyone specific or any specific event.

> He gained *the acceptance* of people in the town.

Because this refers to people, it is more specific - it is *the people's acceptance*, so the article seems appropriate.

In your example, I think it should have the definite article. Acceptance of a drug by medical authorities is certainly a specific decision made by a specific body of experts.

Comment: Hello, Astralbee! Thank you for help! Am I correct in thinking that the definite article must be used in the following sentence, because a specific set of recommendations has been accepted? "We express concern regarding alleged police ill-treatment of suspects, despite THE acceptance of the relevant recommendations"